# Pass parameter in config file

Tags: java, properties

I have a config.properties file in my project, and there I keep several URLs for websites and its' services, for example:

```
main.url=google.com 
another.url=yahoo.com 
etc...
```

and services:

```
main.translate.url=translate.google.com
```

And the thing I wanna do is to pass parameters like:

```
main.translate.url=translate.%%main.url%%
```

so in the method call I'll receive translate.google.com.
Is it possible to do so? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is nothing built-in to replace the parameters. You'll have to program this yourself.

Comment: All you need to do is use a String replace function for the specified delimiter.

Comment: You can use commons-configuration http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation much better to use a library then to program it yourself.